# the GET favicon requests doesn't work and is not logged

Tags: express, favicon

Have built my first app 'by hand' in Express, with satisfaction for me and my customer, but I'm puzzled by the inability to serve the favicon.ico.

Moreover, the GET /favicon.ico doesn't get logged.
This happens also in apps built by express-generator (I use --pug, if this is relevant...)

Have tried to

- serve by myself the route
- use the [serve-favicon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-favicon) middleware
- use the [express-favicon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-favicon) middleware

Any hint would be welcome (I'm a newbie to the Express world), specially regarding how to debug the fact that the GET isn't logged.
Is there something lower level than Watson that could help ?

*edit*

About the low level debugging, I've set

```
export DEBUG=express:*
```

and restarted the server, now I can see a lot of low level processing done. But apparently, no GET /favicon.ico request is arriving at the server:

```
...
  express:router serveStatic  : / +1ms
  express:router router  : / +6ms
  express:router dispatching GET / +1ms
  express:view require "pug" +2ms
  express:view lookup "index.pug" +623ms
  express:view stat "/home/carlo/test/node/cmn_exp_test/views/index.pug" +0ms
  express:view render "/home/carlo/test/node/cmn_exp_test/views/index.pug" +1ms
GET / 304 761.594 ms - -
  express:router dispatching GET /stylesheets/style.css +305ms
  express:router query  : /stylesheets/style.css +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /stylesheets/style.css +1ms
  express:router favicon  : /stylesheets/style.css +0ms
  express:router logger  : /stylesheets/style.css +0ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /stylesheets/style.css +1ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /stylesheets/style.css +0ms
  express:router cookieParser  : /stylesheets/style.css +0ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /stylesheets/style.css +1ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 7.268 ms - -
```

I see the GETs for / and /stylesheets/style.css answered (of course matched in browser console) but not the GET /favicon.ico

Answer (score 1):

Well, I didn't get the request because the browser had cached the previous negative responses.

I cleaned data for localhost and now it's working as expected.

```
...
  express:router serveStatic  : /stylesheets/style.css +0ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 10.756 ms - 111
  express:router dispatching GET /favicon.ico +55ms
  express:router query  : /favicon.ico +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /favicon.ico +0ms
got it
  express:router favicon  : /favicon.ico +1ms
```

Will leave this 'answer' just because the discover process has been instructive for me.